# tmhOAuth oauth/request_token returns 404

Tags: php, twitter, twitter-oauth

having an issue with the Twitter API.  Using [tmhOAuth](https://github.com/themattharris/tmhOAuth).  Constantly getting the following 404 error:

"Sorry, that page does not exist :34"

I can 1/account/verify_credentials and 1/statuses/update perfectly fine but oauth/request_token returns the 404.  The Callback URL in my app settings is set to https://google.com/ for testing purposes.

```
            require_once('tmhOAuth/tmhOAuth.php');

            $connection = new tmhOAuth(array(
            'consumer_key' => '******',
            'consumer_secret' => '******',
            'user_token' => '******',
            'user_secret' => '******'
            ));

            $connection->request('POST',
                    $connection->url('oauth/request_token'),
                    array('oauth_callback' => 'oob')
                    );

            return $connection->response['code'];
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, drawing a blank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this is an old one, but for anyone else looking, you need to add an extra empty string parameter to url(), like so..

```
$connection->request('POST',
    $connection->url('oauth/request_token', ''),
    array('oauth_callback' => 'oob')
);
```